# How to access mysql data on Amazon EBS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have mounted the volume, but i did not know how to access to EBS mysql data from my local machine? Really appreciate for any suggestions.

Comment: What does 'access' means ? Copy, or using by your local mysql server ?

Answer (score 0):

When you start `mysqld`, you need to tell it where data files are to be stored.

Assuming your EBS device is mounted at `/mnt/data`, the following my.cfg(or my.ini) file entry would do the trick for

InnoDB files:

> innodb_data_file_path=/mnt/data

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-configuration.html

For MyISAM:

> datadir=/mnt/data

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_datadir